# Interface com herança em Delphi

Tags: delphi, interface

Preciso fazer uma herança múltipla em Delphi. Lendo alguns artigos, o modo mais apropriado é fazendo uma interface.

Como faço isso, sabendo que temos as classes abaixo como exemplo:

```
type
TPessoa = class
//atributos e métodos
end;

type
TPessoaFisica = class(TPessoa)
//atributos e métodos
end;

type
TPessoaJuridica = class(TPessoa)
//atributos e métodos
end;
```

Atualmente estou criando duas variáveis e instanciando uma, conforme o tipo de seleção do usuário. Queria englobar duas em uma e instanciar conforme a necessidade.

```
var
  CadPJ: TCadastroPJ;
  CadPF: TCadastroPF;
begin

  if rdTipoPessoa.ItemIndex = 0 then
  begin

    try

      CadPF:= TCadastroPF.Create;
      CadPF.LicencaIDCliente:= idCliente;
      CadPF.NomePessoa:= edtNome.Text;
      CadPF.gravarPF;

    finally
      CadPF.Free;
    end;

  end
  else
  begin

    try

      CadPJ:= TCadastroPJ.Create;
      CadPJ.LicencaIDCliente:= idCliente;
      CadPJ.NomeFantasia:= edtNomeFantasia.Text;
      CadPJ.gravarPJ;

    finally
      CadPJ.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Aonde é a herança múltipla que deseja? Se possível, crie um diagrama simples UML para mostrar as heranças.

Comment: Seria para as classes de PF e PJ, pois em ambas já tem o comando para gravar pessoa. Queria apenas instanciar um objeto que na hora posso escolher entre PF e PJ. Do jeito que estou fazendo, preciso criar duas variáveis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você deseja compartilhar o método gravar para as 2 classes Fisica e Jurídica porque o método gravar terá o mesmo comportamento e mesmo código para as 2 classes filhas, então faça uso de herança, declarando esse método na classe base TPessoa e basta chamá-lo de qualquer uma das classes filhas, sem necessidade de declarar 2 métodos uma para cada classe.

```
type
TPessoa = class
  //atributos e métodos
Public
  procedure gravar; 
end;
```

Uso :

```
var
  CadPF: TCadastroPF;
  CadPJ: TCadastroPJ;
begin
    CadPF:= TCadastroPF.Create;
    CadPJ:= TCadastroPJ.Create
    try
      CadPF.Gravar;
      CadPJ.Gravar;
    Finally
      CadPF.Fre;
      CadPJ.Free;
    End;
```

No entanto se o método gravar for diferente para cada classe física e jurídica, seu problema pode ser resolvido usando polimorfismo que é uma das características da POO. Inclua um método abstrato na classe base "TPessoa" com a diretiva virtual e abstract.

Exemplo :

```
type
TPessoa = class
  //atributos e métodos
Public
  procedure gravar; virtual; abstract;
end;

E sobrescreva o método gravar nas 2 classes filhas TPessoaFisica  e TPessoaJuridica  assim :

type
TPessoaFisica = class(TPessoa)
//atributos e métodos
public
   procedure gravar; override;
end;

type
TPessoaJuridica = class(TPessoa)
//atributos e métodos
public
   procedure gravar; override;
end;
```

Nesse caso perceba que métodos abstratos não devem ser escritos na classe onde tiverem sido declarados, então não haverá um corpo de rotina para o método gravar da classe `TPessoa`, haverá apenas a sua declaração.

Escreva os métodos gravar de cada classe filha. Com essa estratégia você tem um método gravar para cada classe instanciada e com apenas um método de chamada e com a vantagem de ter seu método gravar específico para cada uma das classes.

Uma outra técnica para resolução desse problema é aplicando o padrão de projeto *Strategy*, que também usa polimorfismo mas de outra forma, porém creio que a solução que citei deve resolver.

Comment: Obrigado. Vou dar uma estudada nesse conceito. Sim, os métodos de gravação são específicos para cada classe. Apenas o método gravar de pessoas tem características para ambos.